How to Dynamically Set dynamodb:LeadingKeys Condition with JWT Claims in AWS Lambda Function Using Serverless Framework for FineGrained Access Control
I'm working on a proof of concept (POC) for implementing fine-grained access control in DynamoDB using the dynamodb:LeadingKeys condition. I have a Node.js Lambda function that performs CRUD operations on DynamoDB, which is protected by API Gateway with a JWT authorizer.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html
Here's my NodeJS index.js Lambda function code:
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const {
  DynamoDBDocumentClient,
  GetCommand,
  QueryCommand,
  PutCommand,
  DeleteCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");
const express = require("express");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const app = express();
const USERS_TABLE = `${process.env.PROJECT_NAME}-${process.env.ENVIRONMENT}-user-data`;
const client = new DynamoDBClient();
const dynamoDbClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("X-Custom-Header", "Custom header set");
  next();
});

// Get all notes for the authenticated user
app.get("/notes", async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub;
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: USERS_TABLE,
      KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":userId": userId,
      },
    };
    const data = await dynamoDbClient.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    res.json({ data: data.Items });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

// Create a new note for the authenticated user
app.post("/notes", async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub;
  const noteId = crypto.randomUUID();
  const { data } = req.body;
  try {
    const params = {
      TableName: USERS_TABLE,
      Item: {
        userId,
        noteId,
        data,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      },
    };
    await dynamoDbClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
    res.status(201).json({ data: { noteId, data, timestamp: params.Item.timestamp } });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

And here is my serverless.yml configuration:
service: dynamodb-test
frameworkVersion: "3"

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

custom:
  dotenv:
    path: .env
    required: true
    env:
      PROJECT_NAME: PROJECT_NAME
      ENVIRONMENT: ENVIRONMENT
    file: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs20.x
  architecture: arm64
  profile: NONPRODPROFILE
  region: us-west-2
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          Resource:
            - arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:014498888870:table/project-dev-user-data
          Condition:
            ForAnyValue:StringEqualsIgnoreCaseIfExists:
              dynamodb:LeadingKeys: "${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub}"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - cloudwatch:*
          Resource: "*"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
          Resource:
            - "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
          Resource: "*"
  httpApi:
    cors: true
    metrics: true
    payload: '2.0'
    authorizers:
      AwsNamedHttpApiEventAuthorizer:
        type: jwt
        identitySource: $request.header.Authorization
        issuerUrl: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_ZZZZZZZ
        audience:
          - drhdtjgedyrsdtdshyyfdhf

functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /notes
          method: get
          authorizer: AwsNamedHttpApiEventAuthorizer
      - httpApi:
          path: /notes/{noteId}
          method: get
          authorizer: AwsNamedHttpApiEventAuthorizer
      - httpApi:
          path: /notes
          method: post
          authorizer: AwsNamedHttpApiEventAuthorizer
      - httpApi:
          path: /notes/{noteId}
          method: delete
          authorizer: AwsNamedHttpApiEventAuthorizer

The problem I'm encountering is with the following condition in the IAM role:
Condition:
  ForAnyValue:StringEqualsIgnoreCaseIfExists:
    dynamodb:LeadingKeys: "${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub}"

Already Tried Values so far
"${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub}"
"${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"

If I comment out this condition, everything works fine. If I hardcode a specific sub value from a JWT, it works fine for that user. However, I need this condition to dynamically pull the sub value from the JWT claims, but it seems the value is not being correctly substituted.
How can I dynamically set the dynamodb:LeadingKeys condition to the sub value from the JWT claims? Any guidance or best practices for achieving this in the context of a Serverless Framework project would be greatly appreciated.

If I refer to your serverless.yaml the Autorizer used is Cognito as identity provider, the attribut used to check the identitiy for a user in cognito is cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub :
From : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub
Restricts the role to one or more users by UUID. This UUID is the user's identity ID in the identity pool. This value isn’t the sub value from the user’s original identity provider. Amazon Cognito indicates this UUID in the sub claim in the identity pool token.

This sub attribute is mandatory for Cognito user pool and it's value is a UUID 128-bit and it's unique by user in user pool :
From : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-terms.html#terms-uuid

Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)
A 128-bit label that is applied to an object. Amazon Cognito UUIDs are unique per user pool or identity pool, but don't conform to a specific UUID format.

If you need to check with other value as name, email you can check standard attributes from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html
So th policy should look somthing like this, from this AWS post section:
DynamoDB Fine-Grained Access
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/MyTable"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
               "dynamodb:LeadingKeys":  ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
            }
        }
    }
]
}

For the event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.sub, I think this is forwarded from your apigateway to your backend if the authentication is succesful and not available for the IAM policies for dynamic generation and checking. check Here.

I tried this one, not working, Also changed the API gateway type to "REST" from "HTTP" and no luck.

what did you mean by not working ? what error did you get ?

this one directly throwing a serverless validation error
$ sls deploy
Running "serverless" from node_modules
DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
- ENVIRONMENT
- PROJECT_NAME
Environment: win32, node 18.18.2, framework 3.39.0 (local) 3.39.0v (global), plugin 7.2.3, SDK 4.5.1
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
Error:
Unrecognized configuration variable sources: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"

Also tried manually editing the policy document attached to the SLS-created role on the AWS web.
This is the edited policy document
https://pastebin.com/XG1QXrhR
But after applying this, when we call the API, I got this. But is I hardcode the sub the API will work for one user.
"error": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/dynamodb-test-dev-us-west-2-lambdaRole/dynamodb-test-dev-api is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:table/xxx-dev-user-data because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action",


In your table the leading keys is populated by the UUID ? or simply the sub you hard coded when you tried the policy is this the UUID of the user ? because cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub is a UUID like . another question is this a cross account acces ?

userId is the partition key (String) and has valid records. contains the sub-UUID,
This is not a cross-account case.
And also has a sort key setup to the "timestamp" attribute.

can you check with  "Condition":{ "ForAllValues:StringEquals":{ "dynamodb:LeadingKeys":[ "${www.amazon.com:user_id}" ], or ${aws:userid}
